# Trying to LLDB into iOS, but stuck on splash/loading screen

Tags: ios, debugging, remote-debugging, lldb

I'm trying to debug an iOS application via LLDB.

On other iOS applications, I've had no problem, but this particular application is giving me an issue; debugger can't get past a loading/splash screen.

After a debugger starts, I type `continue`. I expect to continue on with the screen to the main activity screen, but it's stuck on it.

Any idea on why that is?

The application is BBM. It would be great if you can replicate this

Edit:

Status as soon as lldb debuggin starts

```
Process 2517 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x000000010496d444 dyld` dyld::findMappedRange(unsigned long)  + 32
dyld`dyld::findMappedRange:
->  0x10496d444 <+32>: cbz    x8, 0x10496d460           ; <+60>
    0x10496d448 <+36>: ldur   x13, [x12, #-0x8]
    0x10496d44c <+40>: cmp    x13, x0
    0x10496d450 <+44>: b.hi   0x10496d460               ; <+60>
    0x10496d454 <+48>: ldr    x13, [x12]
    0x10496d458 <+52>: cmp    x13, x0
    0x10496d45c <+56>: b.hi   0x10496d47c               ; <+88>
    0x10496d460 <+60>: add    x11, x11, #0x1            ; =0x1 
Target 0: () stopped.

thread #1: tid = 0x1e2a0, 0x000000010496d444 'dyld`dyld::findMappedRange(unsigned long) + 32, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
```

Status when I `continue` then `process interrupt`

```
Process 2517 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x000000018348816c libsystem_kernel.dylib` mach_msg_trap  + 8
libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap:
->  0x18348816c <+8>: ret    
libsystem_kernel.dylib'mach_msg_overwrite_trap:    0x183488170 <+0>: mov    x16, #-0x20
    0x183488174 <+4>: svc    #0x80
    0x183488178 <+8>: ret    
libsystem_kernel.dylib'semaphore_signal_trap:    0x18348817c <+0>: mov    x16, #-0x21
    0x183488180 <+4>: svc    #0x80
    0x183488184 <+8>: ret    
libsystem_kernel.dylib'semaphore_signal_all_trap:    0x183488188 <+0>: mov    x16, #-0x22
Target 0: () stopped.

* thread #1: tid = 0x1e2a0, 0x000000018348816c 'libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  thread #7: tid = 0x1e646, 0x00000001834a6314 'libsystem_kernel.dylib`__semwait_signal + 8, name = 'DeadLockMonitorThread'
  thread #8: tid = 0x1e647, 0x000000018348816c 'libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread'
  thread #11: tid = 0x1e667, 0x000000018348816c 'libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'APFileLog'
  thread #17: tid = 0x1e66d, 0x000000018348816c 'libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader'
  thread #18: tid = 0x1e67b, 0x000000018348816c 'libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'AVAudioSession Notify Thread'
  thread #19: tid = 0x1e68b, 0x00000001834a5e1c 'libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 8
  thread #20: tid = 0x1e6ea, 0x000000018348816c 'libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'com.alipay.antlog'
```

Comment: Are you typing "continue" because this particular app stops in the debugger in the course of launching?  If so, what reason did the app give for stopping?  The stop reason is given on the LHS of the PC ribbon in the editor view, or you can issue the "bt" command and look for the "stop reason" listing it the resultant text.

Comment: It stopped for SIGSTOP. I'm assuming that's a normal procedure for debugging no?

Comment: Anti-debugging strategies won't cause a SIGSTOP; they will either just cause the request to attach the debugger to the process to fail, or they will cause the attaching debugger to die.  lldb itself will generate send a SIGSTOP to interrupt the debugee if you request an interruption.  But it shouldn't cause random SIGSTOP's. Is the backtrace when you stop for this SIGSTOP illuminating?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a SIGSTOP at the beginning of the debugging? That has been the case for all of the apps that I debugged. How do you tell if the backtrace is illuminating?

Comment: There is a SIGSTOP that gets sent when  the attach by debugger is successful, but lldb never shows that to you, it auto-continues past it.  If you were stopped at that initial SIGSTOP, there would only be one thread and its stack would just have only one frame.  So if that's what you see, then lldb must have encountered some sort of error in the initial inspection of the binary.  But if you aren't at that point, then you must have gotten stopped for some other reason.

Comment: I can't say without seeing it what the backtrace at your stop point means.  If it doesn't mean anything to you and you don't mind posting it here, please do so and maybe it will make sense to somebody here.

Comment: I posted more information